# How to display several sets in a grouped list in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, tracker

[image: Example]

I'd like to create a list that is divided into several groups, such that items from any group can be hidden.

Right now, the items for each group are held in a separate collection and all collections (5 total) are held in a single object. But I can modify the way they are stored if it will make the code simpler.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you're with WPF framework, you can define ListBox.GroupStyle as well as regular style for inner items. Then bind your listbox to CollectionViewSource something like that:

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(*your-collection-here*);
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(*your-grouping-field-here*));
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription((*your-grouping-field-here*, ListSortDirection.Ascending));
your-listbox-here.ItemsSource = view;
```

All credits go here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/grouping-and-sorting-in-listbox-in-wpf

To expand/collapse the groups you can add a bool property that keeps current state (collapsed or expanded) and take this into account inside your styles (let say, make it visible for expanded items only, change "expand/collapse" chevron icon etc.)

Comment: Would it be possible to use "Expanders", similar to Андрій Петрук's answer, instead of bool property? If so - how?

Comment: @Jecke, you have to add a button to "group style". The purpose of the button is to toggle the bool property in the viewmodel. Then, group style could auto-refresh its button picture (from "down arrow" to "up arrow") and items style could change its visibility at whole (something like Visibility={Binding Path=Expanded, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}})

Answer (score 0):

Try this, easy change ItemTemplate of ListBox to Expander with ListBox.
For example: 
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpyrO.png)
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowVM/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" >
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowVM
{
    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        ItemsList = new List<Group>();
        var items  = new List<Item>();
        items.Add(new Item("Item1")); 
        items.Add(new Item("Item2")); 
        items.Add(new Item("Item3"));
        //items.Add("Item4"); 
        //items.Add("Item5");
        ItemsList.Add(new Group()
        {
            Name = "List1",
            Items = items
        });

        items.Add(new Item("Item4"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Group()
        {
            Name = "List2",
            Items = items
        });
        items.Add(new Item("Item5"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Group()
        {
            Name = "List3",
            Items = items
        });
    }

    public List<Group> ItemsList { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
public class Item
{
    public Item(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I change the list during runtime?

Comment: You need implement interface INotifyPropertyChanged